# Search for maximum and minimum functionality

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, variational-calculus

How can I prove that the trajectory I found after applying the principle of least action corresponds to the minimum of action, and not to the maximum?

Comment: Hi George. Welcome to Phys.SE. Do you know the answer to the following: _In calculus, if you have a stationary point, how would you determine if it is minimum and not a maximum?_

Comment: I would check the second derivative. If this is also applicable for functionality, then I would like to know the technique